# Generating a line chart with data over a 10 days but displaying by hours rather than by days

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I'm trying to generate a chart in Excel. My problem is, that the chart is being generated by days and not by hours. This is why on the 12th October there's only "a spike" visible and not an actual change of the value.

[image]

Data:

```
07.10.2018 16:01   53,00
12.10.2018 10:31   53,00
12.10.2018 11:31   61,00
12.10.2018 13:31   61,00
12.10.2018 14:31   59,00
12.10.2018 17:31   59,00
12.10.2018 18:31   53,00
16.10.2018 11:31   53,00
```

Comment: your data doesn't varies for 9 days ( 7 to 12 = 5 days [53], 12 to 16 = 4 days [53].. ) || and only have "events" in 8 hours..  so.. if the graph is 15 cm long you should expect to get a "spike" of 0.5 cm length. Which is much or less what you get now.. || you can only see pattern if you plot the data ONLY for the 12.10.2018 data. || does it make sense now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my question is Scatter with Straight Lines:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/G0TVP.png